# How do I set the space bar to scroll half the page?

Tags: firefox

When I am on Firefox, I would like the space bar to scroll not the whole page but only half of it in order not to lose focus when I read.

I suppose there must be an easy workaround by changing a value in `about:config` but I can't find it. Or maybe with some Greasemonkey custom script, but I am kind of a noob.

There is also the ["Scroll Half Page" extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scroll-half-page/ihaaiappdjoikdfganmmbabjdaiobpoc) on the Chrome Web store, could that be easily adapted?

I am on Linux Mint 19.1 with the latest version of Firefox.

Comment: I'd like this too.

Comment: My solution was too learn to use the vimium firefox add-on since I am a vim user.  Then you can set some shortcuts for scrolling half a page. I chose 'u' and 'm'.

Comment: If that solution works for you, you're welcome to answer your own question and mark it as accepted the next day.

Comment: I would rather not since it seems to be more of a workaround that vim users might be interested in but I am still expecting a solution that targets the average reader, someone eager for a new tweak but not to change wholly his  probably already overtweaked superuser browsing habits. Don't you agree ?

Comment: I believe the general rule is, if it works for you, then it's an acceptable answer. At the very least, it's a valid answer! It's up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found that works for me is to get the [Vimium](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimium-ff/)  firefox extension and then to insert `map <space> scrollPageDown` in the Custom key mappings text box in the Options.

It will only scroll half the page.

If you happen not to be a Vim user (it's an old and widespread powerful modal text editor that runs in the terminal), you may want to disable all of Vimium keymappings by placing `unmapAll` just **above** the `map <space> scrollPageDown` line.

Comment: Please don't forget to check back in 48 hours to accept your solution so it can be found in the future. [From Review](https://superuser.com/review/late-answers/1083253)

Answer (score 1):

The [Scrollkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrollkey/) extension worked for me:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrollkey/

You can customize the amount of scrolling (in pixels), enable shortcuts for horizontal scrolling and even use <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd> if you don't care about vim-like scrolling with <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd>.